# SwiftUI NavigationView Toggle Tint Color

Tags: swiftui-navigationview

I have two navigation views. The parent is white labeled and the child is black labeled.
When I **revisit** the parent view from the child view the child modifier is still applied. i.e the labels are white instead of black. I understand that applying View modifier to a navigation view **changes all navigations views.**

So my question is how do I toggle between two text colors in navigation views without using view modifier?

```
ParentNavigationView {
    ChildNavigationView {
          .whiteTextColorModifier()
    }
}
.blackTextColorModifier()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the `init(){}` of SwiftUI View.

```
init() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor :  UIColor.white] // Use your own color
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
        UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.whatever
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .white
        UINavigationBar.appearance().isOpaque = true
       }
```

Comment: Still doesn't change back on child dismiss. Maybe should add I'm presenting the child view as a sheet. It's not in a different group view